# Find the point-wise limit of this sequence of function $\{f_n(x)\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the sequence of function $\{f_n(x)\}$ in $[0,1]$ where , $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x=0\\n^2x & \text{ if } x\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]\\-n^2x+n^2 & \text{ if } x\in (\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]\\0 & \text{ if } x\in [\frac{2}{n},1] \end{cases}$$

I have trouble to find the point-wise limit of this sequence of function $\{f_n(x)\}$.

I could not find the limit in the interval $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]$.

Can anyone help me to find the limit in this interval ?

Comment: Note that the interval $[1/n,2/n]$ varies with $n$, so it does not really make sense to "try to find the limit" there. Try to graph the functions and see what happens for $n$ large. (Also, the way you wrote, $f_n$ is not well-defines at the points $1/n$ and $2/n$. I think you meant $f_n(x)=2n^2x-n$ for $x\in[1/n,2/n]$.)

Comment: Why it is NOT well defined ??

Comment: For the point $1/n$: If we use the second line, we have $f_n(1/n)=n^2(1/n)=n$. If we use the third line, we have $f_n(1/n)=-n^2(1/n)+n^2=n^2-n$, which is different of $n$ (if $n\neq 2$). But actually this shouldn't even matter for the solution. The only part that matters are the first and fourth lines (since you're looking at pointwise limits).

Comment: Try to draw some picture. (For different $n$). Then you will see each of them are triangle with thinner and thinner base.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the interval $[1/n, 2/n]$" when you are taking the limit of $n$ to infinity.

**Hint**:

For every $x\in (0,1)$, you can show that there exists some $N$ such that for each $n>N$, $x$ is not an element of $[1/n, 2/n]$.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are saying ...

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 The interval $[1/n, 2/n]$ is moving. When the value of $n$ becomes very big, any value $x>0$ will no longer be an element of $[1/n, 2/n]$, but will instead be an element of $[2/n, 1]$. It will remain a part of this interval for all values of $n$ from there on.